# Our application crashes - How to find the cause of the crash?

Tags: .net, debugging

What happens is we have a contact sync application. Soon after pressing a button that starts the main logic of the syncing in the application, the application stops working and Windows (7 in this case) says our application "has stopped working" after which the only possibility is to close the application via a button entitled "Close the application".

One weird thing is that, on my development machine, the application works fine. It does not crash, does not throw any errors whatsoever. But, when packaged as an installer and installed on other machines it does stop working as described above.

Please let me know what apps I can use for debugging this better, how to find out more about this error, what is triggering it, how it can be solved etc.

Thanks in advance.

*later edit*

This is what is printed out in the event viewer log:

```
Faulting application name: ourappname.exe, version: 1.2.9.0, time stamp: 0x4f3926c8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16915, time stamp: 0x4ec49caf
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000c33bb
Faulting process id: 0xecc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccea61773d12e0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\path\to\ourappname.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: bb3977f0-5654-11e1-9a84-0800275ba797
```

Does that help?

Comment: First place to look will be the Application section of EventViewer.  Exceptions are recorded there, and may give you some insight into what is failing.

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor I've just added more information to the question. I don't see anything that could lead me in the right direction from the EventViewer files though.

Comment: Did you examine the crash dump in C:\Users\dre\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3F91.tmp.mdmp? Is an Unhandled Exception handler attached?

Comment: @PVitt, what application would be best to use to open up that .mdmp file? It's not text apparently, Notepad doesn't open in in legible text.

Comment: @Andrei: One of the first hits in bing: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/mdmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a [global uncaught exception handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/04/28/how-to-handle-net-unhandled-exceptions-gracefully.aspx) and log the error. For good measure, you can [write a memory dump of your application](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dbghelp/MiniDumpWriteDump.html) and use [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) along with [SOS.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to get a rather precise look at what's going on in your app (dbghelp.dll ships alongside WinDbg in Debugging Tools for Windows).

Comment: The global exception handler doesn't log anything when the application crashes. Could that mean that the exception isn't caught by the 2 examples given in that article? I haven't yet tried writing a memory dump.